# In C#, I set the relative path of the DLL, but an exception is still thrown and the corresponding DLL cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

This is the complete App.config file：

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="entityFramework"
    type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"
        description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
      description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="aceLibs;hoopsLibs;frameworkLibs;sqLiteLibs"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This is the run directory：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tSL4.png)

Cannot find the corresponding dll when running, what might be wrong?
I am sure there is no problem with the dll itself. I just changed the relative path of the dll and the program throws an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that this is a special case. My project is a DLL file. The privatePath setting is invalid. You must change the privatePath attribute of the EXE file that loads this DLL file.